# jVectorMap - How to highlight region that have markers in them?

Tags: jvectormap

I have a problem with jVectorMap, I don't know how may I highlight the regions that have markers in them. Does anybody knows a way for doing this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't provide an automatic way of highlighting regions based on markers but you can use the `series` option to change behavior of regions / markers.

If you want to highlight regions on map initialization, you need to pass a list of objects with the code of your regions and a key color value.

Imagine you want to highlight following regions: `BE, NL, DE`. You need to pass this to the series values:

```
{ 'BE': '1', 'NL': '1', 'DE': '1' }
```

And the sample code where the value `1` is attributed to the color `#4169E1` (as an example)

```
new jvm.WorldMap({
    map: '',
    container: $(''),
    series: {
        regions: [{
            scale: {
                '1': '#4169E1'
            },
            attribute: 'fill',
            values: { 'BE': '1', 'NL': '1', 'DE': '1' }
        }]
    }
});
```

Because you already have the list of markers, you can easily build this `highlight region list`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was hoping that there was another solution, because I don't want to calculate marker/region membership. Hope someone can provide another solution, if no I'll mark your answer in a few days. Thanks

Comment: How does your `markers` array looks like? Do you have a country / region code attached to it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just have coordinates and the names of the countries, no region code. The only way for me seems to be to get country code from server and then get them in page. I already don't know if I want to do that.